# How to format on save with the Deno VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno, deno-fmt

I am using the [vscode-deno](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=denoland.vscode-deno) extension and eventhough I turned on `deno.enable`, `deno.lint` and `deno.unstable` in my vscode settings, it does not format my code on save, which I suppose is the expected behavior.

I instead used the [RunOnSave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave) extension to hack my way into running a `deno fmt` on file save, but I was wondering if there was a way to do that with the Deno extension alone?

My `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.lint": true,
  "deno.unstable": true,
  "emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "match": "\\.ts$",
        "cmd": "deno fmt ${file}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found it, I have to turn on formatting on save and specifying the Deno extension as the default formatter

```json
{
  "deno.enable": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning you can set the default formatter to only touch ts files using this:
`"[typescript]": {"editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"}`

Comment: And maybe you want to nest format on save to typescript to avoid other file extensions get automatically formatted. Like so;
```js
"[typescript]": {
      "editor.formatOnSave": true,
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"
    }
```

Comment: To specify config options, add `"deno.config": "./deno.jsonc",` to `settings.json`, then add a `deno.jsonc` as per https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.2/getting_started/configuration_file

Answer (score 0):

Just another addition which might scratch your head a little bit. It took me a couple of hours.

My `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "licenser.license": "MPLv2",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": "always",
    "source.organizeImports": "always",
  },
  "[typescript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "denoland.vscode-deno"
  },
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.config": "./deno.jsonc",
}
```

My `deno.jsonc`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "lib": ["deno.window"],
    "strict": true
  },
  "lint": {
    "include": ["src/"],
    "exclude": ["src/testdata/", "data/fixtures/**/*.ts"],
    "rules": {
      "tags": ["recommended"],
      "include": ["ban-untagged-todo"],
      "exclude": ["no-unused-vars"]
    }
  },
  "fmt": {
    "useTabs": false,
    "lineWidth": 80,
    "indentWidth": 2,
    "semiColons": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "proseWrap": "preserve",
    "include": ["src/", "main.ts"],
    "exclude": ["src/testdata/", "data/fixtures/**/*.ts"]
  },
  "lock": false,
  "nodeModulesDir": false,
  "test": {
    "include": ["src/"],
    "exclude": ["src/testdata/", "data/fixtures/**/*.ts"]
  },
  "tasks": {
    "start": "deno run main.ts"
  },
  "imports": {}
}
```

In your `settings.json`, the formatter works only when I add `[typescript]` part.

And also, check your `fmt.include`. I forgot to add `main.ts` into it.